# Usage of property decorator for private attributes in classes in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I've started learning Python recently, and there are some topics I cannot really understand. One is the usage of the decorators in user defined objects, or encapsulation more generally. I mean, let's consider for example:

```
class Dog:
   def __init__(self,name,age):
      self.name=name
      self.age=age
```

Ok so now I have the object 'Dog'. If I make its attribute privates by adding '__' in the constructor, I won't be able to access them. In order to do so, I will have to use, for example, the decorator 'property', which has attributes (not sure how to call them actually)'getter', 'setter' and 'deleter'. So I make, for example, the name private. I have:

```
class Dog:
   def __init__(self,name,age):
      self.__name=name
      self.age=age
   @property
   def name(self):
      return self.__name
   @name.setter
   def name(self,name)
      self.__name=name
   @name.deleter
   def name(self)
      del self.__name
```

Now the question is: how is this different from just letting name be public? I would understand if I could only read the name value, or don't delete it, but if I give the user the possibility to read, write and delete the attribute... why do I bother making it private in the first place?

I don't know, maybe this was just a "syntax exercise" and in fact you are meant to give the user only a proper subset of those abilities.

Comment: It's not different (except that it's slightly less efficient). There's absolutely no point to the properties if they don't have any _logic_ in them. The whole benefit is that you don't have to write getters and setters upfront and can add a layer of abstraction, if needed, without changing the API.

Comment: So you are only meant to use this encapsulation only when you don't want the user to do all that stuff? Like, for instance if you want the user to be able to only read an attribute

Comment: Yes, or if you want to add validation to the value being set.

Comment: (Also note you shouldn't use `__name_mangling` unless that's really the specific behaviour you want: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance).

Comment: What do you mean by "add validation"? And, "__name_mangling"?

Comment: Validation is like saying "Stephen" isn't a valid name for a dog, so the assignment should fail. If you look up name mangling in Python there are good explanations on e.g. SO, it's to _stop_ subclasses accessing attributes so isn't generally a good idea.

Comment: Maybe you have already read [this article](https://realpython.com/python-property/), but I deeply suggest to read it for a better understanding of this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more thorough example of why you would want to have a private attribute: data type validation (as pointed out by the other answers).

Let's say that you've been using the `Dog` class for a few weeks, and a new bug has come up that happens when the `name` attribute is (for whatever reason) set to a value that's not a string. You now need to change the code in order to enforce that a `Dog`'s `name` is indeed a string, by raising an informative Exception. How do you do that?

Your first idea may be to simply check the `name`'s data type after creating a new `Dog` (using the `isinstance` [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)):

```
my_dog = Dog(name='Max', age=5)
if not isinstance(my_dog.name, str):
    raise ValueError("The Dog's name is not a string")
```

This works, but there's a clear issue here: you need to 1) change *every line of code where a `Dog` is created*, and 2) you need to tell anyone who ever uses your `Dog` class that, *by the way, remember to check for the `name`'s data type*. This is clearly a lot of work, and not future-proof by any means - what if you or another user forgets to do this check? What if no one ever reads your documentation on the `Dog` class?

You may then think to perform this check in the `__init__` method:

```
def class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise ValueError("The Dog's name is not a string")
        self.__name = name
        self.age = age
```

This cuts down on the work, but it doesn't stop someone from modifying the `Dog`'s `name` after it was instantiated:

```
my_dog = Dog(name='Max', age=5)
my_dog.name = 10  # oops, wrong value!
```

What we want to do is to actually *move this type-checking functionality to a method that runs every time the `name` attribute gets set* - which is exactly what the setter method (the one decorated with the `@name.setter` decorator) does:

```
def class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.age = age

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, new_name)
        if not isinstance(new_name, str):
            raise ValueError("The Dog's name is not a string")
        self.__name = new_name
```

Now the `name`'s data type is always checked for, both during instantiation (in the `__init__` method) and afterwards.

Data type validation is simply an example. The point of using private attributes and their getters/setters is to combine *attribute access* with some *custom functionality*. If you desire *no functionality whatsoever* when accessing/modifying the attribute, you're correct in your observation that you don't need to bother making it private and writing the getter/setter methods in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

The advantage of properties is that from the viewpoint of the user of your class, it's syntactically the same as plain attribute access. So you can add logic (validation etc.) at any time without changing the class's interface and breaking the code that uses it. You can even swap in different versions of the class (e.g. with properties that do logging during development, without properties for production) and the caller won't even notice.

Contrast this to a language like Java where best practice is to always write getter/setter methods even if you don't need them, because you *might* need them *later,* but can't add them later without changing the API and thereby breaking code that uses the class.

BTW, there are no truly private attributes in Python. The leading `__` is intended to keep names from conflicting among subclasses of the base class, where that might be a problem.

Comment: I...kinda lost you, but I get that it's pretty useful. Don't know what you mean by validation and I don't know Java, but thanks!

Comment: Validation refers to the fact that a setter could make sure that the property is assigned the correct type of data with an acceptable value. for example a `month` property could be constrained to integers only and values of 1-12